OpenAI Speech To Text Api not working properly
I am developing a C# WinForms application with .NET Core 8. It is OpenAI C# Visitor application by voice interactively. The purpose of this application is to ask the user for their first name, last name, who they are visiting, and the reason for the visit, all through voice input. It then converts the received information into text and saves it to a database. I am using the NAudio library to capture the user's voice. To convert the speech to text, I am using OpenAI's Speech to Text API. While it works quite well sometimes, other times it doesn't work properly at all. What steps can I take to ensure it works correctly?
For recording
 var waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
 waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

if (waveFile == null)
{
    waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilePath, waveIn.WaveFormat);
}

waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);

For OpenAI
 byte[] audioData = File.ReadAllBytes(outputFilePath);
 string model = "whisper-1";
 string lang = "en";
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

     var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
     var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(audioData);
     byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");
     requestContent.Add(byteContent, "file", "audio.wav");

     var modelContent = new StringContent(model);
     requestContent.Add(modelContent, "model");

     var langContent = new StringContent(lang);
     requestContent.Add(langContent, "language");

     var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", requestContent);
     var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); userResponseText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TranscriptionOutput>(responseContent);
     //chat
     richTextBox1.Text = userResponseText.Text +"\r\n" + richTextBox1.Text;
}

The speech and the resulting texts are very different.
